Type error: Property 'id' does not exist on type generated by prisma
Im generating my application models from database using prisma.
So I have many items like:barber,stylist,users,...
In my next.js project I need to extend stylist so:
export interface CustomStylist extends stylist {
  services: service[] | undefined;
}

All stuffs seems to be corrects and there is no errors in app. (Even when I run command: npm run build) it shows successfully result:

But when I deploy source code in server . It throws an error:

What happened and how can I fix errors?
